# Create HTML Link To More HTML Code

Tags: php, html

I have file1.php which generates an html website. I have file2.html which contains only html code. Is it possible to create a generated hyperlink within file1.php to link to the code within file2.html? I want file1.php to generate a html website that is not dependent on whether or not file2.html exists.

I can get the contents of file2.html using php's file_get_contents function, but how do I hyperlink to the code saved within the return of that function?

So for example, I would click the hyperlink and I would see file2.html just as if I opened file2.html using any web browser. I want it to look as if I am linking to an external file (file2.html) but actually work as if file2.html doesnt exist during executing of the html website that file1.php generated.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, why can't you just add a `<a>` tag with `href="file2.html"` to your html generated in `file1.php` ?

Comment: Because that requires file2.html to always exist. There will be times when it wont exist, so I would rather copy the code, and create a link to it when I run the php script.

Answer (score 1):

file1.php

```
<a href="show_contents.php?file=file2.html">Link</a>
```

show_contents.php

```
// perform checks to make sure $_GET['file'] exists then display contents
// you will also have to do some validation on the variable passed in to file so 
// the user can't change the path to be whatever they want
echo file_get_contents($_GET['file'])
```

**Update based on comment:**

file1.php

```
if (isset($_GET['file')) {
    // perform checks to make sure $_GET['file'] exists then display contents
    // you will also have to do some validation on the variable passed in to file so 
    // the user can't change the path to be whatever they want
    echo file_get_contents($_GET['file'])
    exit();
}

<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?file=file2.html">Link</a>
```

Comment: Isnt the show_contents.php file now a new dependency every time I run file1.php? I would prefer to have file1.php not be dependent on any external files.

Comment: Still confused by this answer. Surely the hyperlink should be updated as well? Did you mean to put the updated solution in a function?

Comment: sorry the file name should have been replaced

Comment: Can you help me understand though? That hyperlink looks like its just linking to file2.html. I want file1.php to copy the contents of file2.html when run, and then create a link to the contents of file2.html rather then linking to the actual file. It is not clear what is going on here, so I am having trouble determining if this is actually doing it (it isnt when I run it in my code).